# Long (BigInt) is not supported with Jet.int

Tags: entity-framework

Code First models that contain long property can't map to access the database when using `jetEntityFrameworkProvider`.
The problem is that I can't change the data type of that property from Long to Int.

Here is the error:

```
Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 
'Edm.Int64[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 
'Transfere_Document_Number' in type 'Data.MoneyTransfer' is not 
compatible with 'Jet.int[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 
'Transfere_Document_Number' in type 
'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.MoneyTransfer'.
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a whole 3 days working on this problem and some others related to JetEntityFramewrok, I came up with the sloution.

If the Long Column is not a primary key nor forigen key, Just add the following Data Annotation attribute above it:

```cs
[Column("Column_Name", TypeName="BigInt")]
```

But, If it was a primary key then the same sloution will work except you'll loss the auto new value identification. Means that you'll have to manually calculate the Column new Value.

I use the following method, anyone have a better approach, please write it on a comment or edit the answer and add it at the end (Thanks in advance):

```cs
Long id = 1;
If (Context.TableName.Count() > 0)
     Id = Context.TableName.Max(x=>x.id) + 1;

TableName obj = new TableName(){ Id = id};
```